# google map is not show in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

it works fine in chrome. but when loading by firefox, the right side for google map will leave blank. and it also seem like all code functionality works fine(Spring mvc and Jquery)
you can also see the application in sameplaces.heroku.com. Thanks

```
 <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/layout.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA8_h_OaZwi_KRiDev5M8PUxhKRuKbOj1Q&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
            $("input[type=submit],input[type=button],a,button")
                .button()
                .click(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
      });
      var initialLocation;
      var siberia = new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105);
      var newyork = new google.maps.LatLng(40.69847032728747, -73.9514422416687);
      var browserSupportFlag =  new Boolean();
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
          browserSupportFlag = true;
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
          map.setCenter(initialLocation);
          }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
          });
        }
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        else {
          browserSupportFlag = false;
          handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
        }

        function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
          if (errorFlag == true) {
            alert("Geolocation service failed.");
            $(".address_search_div").show();
            initialLocation = newyork;
          } else {
              alert("Your browser doesn't support geolocation. We've placed you in Siberia.");
              initialLocation = siberia;
            }
        map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        }
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="35%" height="100%"><t:insertAttribute name="menu"/></td>
            <td width="65%" height="100%"><t:insertAttribute name="map"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the element `map-canvas`?

Comment: it is in another jsp file, called "map.jsp", I am using Spring MVC + Tiles2. the "map.jsp" is simple now, only have <div id="map-canvas"></div> in that page

Comment: You have two `link` tags in header. The last one is properly closed with `/>`, the first one is not.

Comment: it is not the cause for our problem.

Comment: Where is element with class `.address_search_div`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working on both Chrome and FF. I got rid of all yours CSS and jquery includes to simplify everything. I added in just this style:

```
    html { height: 100% }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
    #map-canvas { height: 100% }
```

Chrome was OK, FF reported:

```
Error in parsing value for 'background'. Declaration dropped.
   -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000, #fff)
```

Solution was this styling (width was missing):

```
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% ; width: 100%}
  body { height: 100%; width:100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100%; width:100% }
</style>
```

Explanation about this solution is here [Google Maps V3 Polyline loading fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546818/google-maps-v3-polyline-loading-fails). Note there was the same error message about background.

So, check your styling. It seems that code is OK.